# Torch default directory

Tags: torch

I installed Torch using the instructions at http://torch.ch/docs/getting-started.html and it created a directory called `~/torch`.

Is it possible for me to rename the default torch directory to `~/.torch`, for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, you can rename it as you wish, but after renaming it, rerun the commands:

```
./clean.sh
./install.sh
```